# Why I can't get data from CD-ROM using INT 13h AH = 42h, DL = 0x0e in BIOS?

Tags: assembly, bootloader, bios

I want to read code of OS bootloader from CD-ROM. On the Internet I read that to do it I have to use INT 13h AH = 42h (Extended Read Sectors From Drive). I did it, compiled code and created ISO file. Tests on two different virtual machines failed, bootloader code hadn't copied to the HDD. Can anyone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong and fix the problem?

The source of bootloader is following:

```
try_read_os_from_cd:
    mov ah, 42h
    mov dl, e0h
    mov si, DAP_table
    int 13h
    jnc print_copy_boot_msg
    print 'C'
    print 'D'
    print 'R'
    print 'E'
```

```
print_copy_boot_msg:
    println_string OS_boot_coping_started ; println is a macro
try_write_boot_to_hdd:
    mov ax, 0
    call l2hts ;l2hts converts LBA address to CHS address
    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, os_boot_hdd
    mov ah, 3h
    mov al, 1
    mov dl, 80h
    int 13h
    jnc success_copy
    print 'H'
    print 'W'
    print 'E'
```

The DAP_table:

```
DAP_table:
    db 16
    db 0
    dw 1
    dw os_boot_hdd
    dw 0
    dq 1

times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa

os_boot_hdd:
```

After running qemu x86_64 machine with created ISO file I got the message "OS boot successfully copied to HDD!". It means that reading from CD finished without errors and data copied to HDD. But when I checked out HDD content I didn't find the code of bootloader.

Then I ran VMWare x86 Virtual Machine with created ISO file and saw "CDRE". According to the code something went wrong while reading from ISO.

If I use INT 13h AH = 2h and run both virtual machines from floppy disk, I won't get any problem.

Comment: How are you booting from CD ("hard disk emulation", "floppy disk emulation" or "no emulation")? Note that CD-ROM might be `dl=0xE0` or `dl=0xC0` or anything else or nothing if you used disk emulation and didn't ask BIOS to terminate the disk emulation, and `LBA = 1` is the second (2048-byte) sector on the disk (and the first 16 sectors are supposed to be zeros and should never be a CD-ROM boot loader).

Comment: @Brendan I just ran VM. As I know, you have to do special interrupt to use emulation. I didn't do it. Almost all of my code is given in the description, except first part with initializing ds, ss, es and macros definitions. Maybe the problem is incorrect LBA. I'll try change and run bootloader again.

Comment: When booting from CD, firmware examines a table of "boot records" on the CD (partly so the same CD can have a boot loader for 80x86, one for PowerPC, one for Itanium ,..) and your boot record tells firmware how to boot (emulate a floppy using a floppy image on the CD, emulate a hard disk using a hard disk image on the CD, or don't do any emulation). You need to find and read a specification called "`"El Torito" Bootable CD-ROM Format Specification`" which describes the disk format, new BIOS functions to control emulation, and how it's supposed to work/be used.